# Django filter by condition

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm, django-filter

I have a queryset that I want to paginate through alphabetically.

```
employees = Employee.nodes.order_by('name')
```

I want to compare the first letter of the employee's name `name[0]` to the letter that I am iterating on. - but I don't know how to filter based on conditions applied to my attribute.

```
employees_by_letter = []      

for letter in alphabet: 
    employees_by_this_letter = employees.filter(name[0].lower()=letter)
    employees_by_letter.append(employees_by_this_letter)

  """error -- SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression"""
```

I suppose I could iterate through each employee object and append a value for their first letter... but there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well this is Python, and in Python parameter names are **identifiers**. You can not drop some sort of expression into it.

Django has however some ways to do advanced filtering. In your case, you want to use the [**`__istartswith`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-istartswith) filter:

```
employees_by_letter = [
    employees.filter(name__istartswith=letter)
    for letter in alphabet
]
```

This is a list comprehension that will generate such that for every `letter in alphabet`, the corresponding queryset is in the list.

Note however that since you eventually will fetch every element, I would actually recommend iterating (or performing a `groupby` for example).

Like:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Lower
fromiteratools import groupby

employees_by_letter = {
    k: list(v)
    for k, v in groupby(
        Employee.annotate(lowname=Lower('name')).nodes.order_by('lowname'),
        lambda x: x.lowname[:1]
    )
}
```

this will construct a dictionary with as key the lowercase letter (or an empty string, if there are strings with an empty name), and these all map to lists of `Employee` instances: the `Employee`s with a name that start with that letter. So that means we perform only a single query on the database. Django querysets are however lazy, so in case you plan to only really fetch a few of the querysets, then the former can be more efficient.